# how to fix the location of nodes while visualizing graph in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I'm visualizing graph , which generated ramdomly. I will change color of each node in some rules and wanna track change of graph nodes' color. (Maybe I can make gif with the images of graph)

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
n = 50
p = 0.12

np.random.seed(42)

G = nx.gnp_random_graph(n, p)
color_map = np.random.choice(['blue', 'red'], size=50)
nx.draw(G, node_color=color_map, with_labels=True)
plt.savefig('2.png')
nx.draw(G, node_color=color_map, with_labels=True)
plt.savefig('3.png')
```

[2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLGIY.png)
[3.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrSqI.png)

but I found put that the nodes' location change every time I plot. I expected that the two drawings would overlap perfectly and look like one. but as you can see in the second plot, every node's location changed. How can I fix nodes' location?

another way to make random graph

Answer (score 1):

The `nx.draw` functions have a parameter `pos` that lets you supply a pre-calculated dictionary of positions keyed by node.

Therefore, you can use `pos = nx.spring_layout(G)` before the first `nx.draw`, then add `pos = pos` into the parameters of each subsequent `nx.draw`